# How to selectRowAtIndexPath in main table view after search table view, using indexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

My app's main tableview contains a list with UISearchBar. The app allows users to select multiple list entries, and send them by email.

When a user selects a list entry within the searchbar, the following code stores the selected items' information:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Code to store description of selected cell
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    println(selectedCell)
    // Code to store indexPath of selected cell
    rowToSelect = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    println(rowToSelect)
    // Code to store textLabel of selected cell
    selectedCellTitle = selectedCell?.textLabel?.text ?? ""
    println("The stored cell is called \(selectedCellTitle)")
}
```

Then, I use the following code to reselect the selected cell in search view in the main table view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredPublications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("fullTitle") as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredPublications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("journal") as? String
            println(filteredPublications)
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = publications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("fullTitle") as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = publications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("journal") as? String
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top)
        }
return cell
}
```

This does not work, because the indexPath for a list entry in search view is not equal to the indexPath for that same entry in main tableView. How can I select the equal entry in the main tableView, after returning from search view?

(One suggestion is to store the textLabel in search view, like selectedCellTitle in the code above. Then, I can loop through all cells in main tableView, and find the cell that has an equal title as the variable selectedCellTitle. Then, I can store the indexPath of that cell. Then, I can reselect the cell. However, I don't know how to write the loop through all cells, and filter the cell that has a cell title equal to selectedCellTitle. My attempt is below, but doesn't work.)

```
for publication in publications {
    if let fullTitle = publication.valueForKey("fullTitle") as? NSString {
        if fullTitle.containsString(selectedCellTitle) {
            var rowToSelectIndexPath = publication.indexPath
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelectIndexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than keep track of the selected indexPath, keep track of the object that lies at that indexPath.  You can then determine at what index that object falls in the main `publications` array.  Then you can build the correct indexPath in the main table view.

You don't indicate what object class is held in the `publications` array, but for argument's sake let's call it `Publication`.  Then you will need to declare a property to use to keep track of the selected publication:

```
var selectedPublication : Publication? = nil
```

Then, set the value in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        selectedPublication = filteredPublications[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        selectedPublication = publications[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Then, when you dismiss the searchController:

```
if let selection = selectedPublication {
    // use this if publications is an NSArray...
    let selectedRow = publications.indexOfObject(selection)
    // or this if publications is a Swift array...
    let selectedRow = find(publications, selection)
    if let row = selectedRow {
        let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row, inSection:0)
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
    }
}
```

(where you put this code depends on how you've implemented the searchController - perhaps in `viewWillAppear`, or in a searchController delegate method).

Note that you shouldn't call `selectRowAtIndexPath` from within `cellForRowIndexPath` - it will be called every time a new cell is displayed, which might give some weird animation effects.